# mysql explain slow where on left joined table

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-execution-plan

Playing with a mysql and thinking how to solve one thing in the future. I want to retrieve statuses which are posted by my friends (specific user ids) or are posted inside of the group I follow.

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_F23501207E3C61F9` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1567559 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `group_status` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_F23501207E3C61F9` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I fed both tables with 1M rows.

The query I am running:

```
SELECT s.id, s.status, gs.group_id
FROM status s 
LEFT JOIN group_status gs
ON s.id = gs.id
WHERE 
s.user_id IN (55883,122024,442468,846269,903941,980896,192660,20608,525056,563457)
OR gs.group_id IN (78,79,79,80,80,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,89,91,92,92,94,98)
ORDER BY s.id DESC
LIMIT 15
```

The result:

[image]

**Question one:**

Shouldn't be the extra role like: "using index" instead of "where" ?

**Question two:**

Why is the response time so slow? **2,3s**

[image]

**Edit after Tim's answer:**

[image]

1. The filesort behaviour I guess is normal when using union no?
2. Why there is 'using where' in the second row of explain? If in the third is 'using where, using index' ?
3. In case of how many returned rows from selects you think this would get slow?

The union select seems to be super fast but there is only few rows returning each select currently. I will try to select more rows in each select.

Comment: The filesort might be caused by status column, which is defined as Text.

Comment: `s.id = gs.id` is making my brain spin!  Why do you have an id for statuses and an id for group statuses; furthermore, why do they have the same semantics (since you are joining on them)??

Comment: Rick what's your naming suggestion ? And do u have anything to say to the question itself please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have an "OR" on different columns, mysql may use none of your indexes.

Usually we can solve the problem using "UNION" two separate queries with each matching one of the criteria.

```
SELECT id, status, group_id FROM
(
  SELECT s.id, s.status, gs.group_id
  FROM status s 
  LEFT JOIN group_status gs
  ON s.id = gs.id
  WHERE 
  s.user_id IN (55883,122024,442468,846269,903941,980896,192660,20608,525056,563457)
UNION 
  SELECT s.id, s.status, gs.group_id
  FROM status s 
  LEFT JOIN group_status gs
  ON s.id = gs.id
  WHERE 
  gs.group_id IN (78,79,79,80,80,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,89,91,92,92,94,98)
) t
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 15
```

However, in your case, this may NOT help if either query returns large number of records.

Your status column is defined as text, which may cause the file sort. You can check it to a long varchar to see if the filesort goes way. Or try this to avoid worse case scenario:

```
SELECT ss.id, group_id, ss.status 
FROM (
SELECT id, group_id FROM
(
  SELECT s.id,  gs.group_id
  FROM status s 
  LEFT JOIN group_status gs
  ON s.id = gs.id
  WHERE 
  s.user_id IN (55883,122024,442468,846269,903941,980896,192660,20608,525056,563457)
UNION 
  SELECT s.id,  gs.group_id
  FROM status s 
  LEFT JOIN group_status gs
  ON s.id = gs.id
  WHERE 
  gs.group_id IN (78,79,79,80,80,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,89,91,92,92,94,98)
) t
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 15
) f
JOIN status ss
ON f.id =ss.id 
ORDER BY ss.id
```

Comment: Thx for comment. I edited my answer with more details, questions

Comment: In most cases, you should use union for this kind of query. It can get slower when your queries return very large percentage (50%, etc)  and you have many columns returned, especially blob fields.

Comment: I changed the "text" to "varchar (20000)" but is the same. Hmmm I am not sure what are you trying to achieve in your second example? Can u reveal what are your thoughts there?

Comment: The second sample reduces the temp result data size significantly.

Comment: I tried to add add bigger range for s.user_id IN () so the whole first sub-query returns 25 000 statuses and the overall performance of that query was about 150ms (your second query). you mean reducing by returning only the id, group id from the subqueries? and then joining again the status table only for that 15 results to get rest of the informations?

Comment: Yes that's the idea. Compare the results to find which one you need. SQL has to get the 25000 rows and some from the second union part, do a sort before it can return the 15 result you need. You want the sort in memory and you have to keep the data as small as you can.

Comment: All right. Thx and I would like to keep being in touch with you (services@trki.sk) and in a case you like sun and beach we could have a full time position for u https://twitter.com/TrkiSF2/status/599263752958124032 :)